# WaitForSingleObject is timing out when returned data is over 4150 bytes

Tags: vb6

Using `VBA 6.0` and `WaitForSingleObject`. I'm relatively new to `VBA 6` so I'm having this problem. Unfortunately, I cannot upgrade the project to VS 2010. I am creating a pipe out to a cmd shell and passing a command line then waiting for the results. If I run the exact command as it is being sent, from a cmd window it works perfectly and the `errorlevel` always returns 0. But running the commands with `WaitForSingleObject` returns zero when the returned data is less than 4151 bytes and times out with a 258 error if it's 4151 or more.

The timeout has been increased to 60 seconds and does not make a difference. If it is set to infinite, it never moves forward (I've let it sit for hours). The failing commands, when run from cmd, finish the output in about a second. Here's the full code (the error handling is commented out just so that I can see what data is returned. It does show the first 4150 bytes of data.):

```
  Option Explicit

  Private Type SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      nLength As Long
      lpSecurityDescriptor As Long
      bInheritHandle As Long
  End Type

  Private Type PROCESS_INFORMATION
      hProcess As Long
      hThread As Long
      dwProcessId As Long
      dwThreadId As Long
  End Type

  Private Type STARTUPINFO
      cb As Long
      lpReserved As Long
      lpDesktop As Long
      lpTitle As Long
      dwX As Long
      dwY As Long
      dwXSize As Long
      dwYSize As Long
      dwXCountChars As Long
      dwYCountChars As Long
      dwFillAttribute As Long
      dwFlags As Long
      wShowWindow As Integer
      cbReserved2 As Integer
      lpReserved2 As Byte
      hStdInput As Long
      hStdOutput As Long
      hStdError As Long
  End Type

  Private Const WAIT_LONG             As Long = 60000
  Private Const WAIT_INFINITE         As Long = (-1&)
  Private Const STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW  As Long = &H1
  Private Const STARTF_USECOUNTCHARS  As Long = &H8
  Private Const STARTF_USESTDHANDLES  As Long = &H100
  Private Const SW_HIDE               As Long = 0&
  Private Const SW_SHOWNORMAL         As Long = 1

  Private Declare Function CreatePipe Lib "kernel32" (phReadPipe As Long, phWritePipe As Long, lpPipeAttributes As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, ByVal nSize As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function CreateProcess Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateProcessA" (ByVal lpApplicationName As Long, ByVal lpCommandLine As String, lpProcessAttributes As Any, lpThreadAttributes As Any, ByVal bInheritHandles As Long, ByVal dwCreationFlags As Long, lpEnvironment As Any, ByVal lpCurrentDriectory As String, lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO, lpProcessInformation As PROCESS_INFORMATION) As Long
  Private Declare Function ReadFile Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpBuffer As Any, ByVal nNumberOfBytesToRead As Long, lpNumberOfBytesRead As Long, lpOverlapped As Any) As Long
  Private Declare Function CloseHandle Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hObject As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function WaitForSingleObject Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hHandle As Long, ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
  Private Declare Sub GetStartupInfo Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetStartupInfoA" (lpStartupInfo As STARTUPINFO)
  Private Declare Function GetFileSize Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hFile As Long, lpFileSizeHigh As Long) As Long

  Public Function Redirect(szBinaryPath As String, szCommandLn As String) As String
      Dim tSA_CreatePipe              As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrc        As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      Dim tSA_CreateProcessThrd       As SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES
      Dim tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo    As PROCESS_INFORMATION
      Dim tStartupInfo                As STARTUPINFO
      Dim hRead                       As Long
      Dim hWrite                      As Long
      Dim bRead                       As Long
      Dim abytBuff()                  As Byte
      Dim lngResult                   As Long
      Dim szFullCommand               As String
      Dim lngExitCode                 As Long
      Dim lngSizeOf                   As Long
      Dim intReturn                   As Integer

      tSA_CreatePipe.nLength = Len(tSA_CreatePipe)
      tSA_CreatePipe.lpSecurityDescriptor = 0&
      tSA_CreatePipe.bInheritHandle = True

      tSA_CreateProcessPrc.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessPrc)
      tSA_CreateProcessThrd.nLength = Len(tSA_CreateProcessThrd)

      If (CreatePipe(hRead, hWrite, tSA_CreatePipe, 0&) <> 0&) Then
          tStartupInfo.cb = Len(tStartupInfo)
          GetStartupInfo tStartupInfo

          With tStartupInfo
              .hStdOutput = hWrite
              .hStdError = hWrite
              .dwFlags = STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW Or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES
              .wShowWindow = SW_HIDE
          End With

          szFullCommand = """" & szBinaryPath & """" & " " & szCommandLn
          frmCszKUpNS.FullCommand.Text = szFullCommand

          lngResult = CreateProcess(0&, szFullCommand, tSA_CreateProcessPrc, tSA_CreateProcessThrd, _
                                    True, 0&, 0&, vbNullString, tStartupInfo, tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo)

          If (lngResult <> 0&) Then
              lngResult = WaitForSingleObject(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, WAIT_LONG)

              lngSizeOf = GetFileSize(hRead, 0&)
              If (lngSizeOf > 0) Then
                  ReDim abytBuff(lngSizeOf - 1)
                  If ReadFile(hRead, abytBuff(0), UBound(abytBuff) + 1, bRead, ByVal 0&) Then
                      Redirect = StrConv(abytBuff, vbUnicode)
                  End If
              End If
              Call GetExitCodeProcess(tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess, lngExitCode)
              CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hThread
              CloseHandle tSA_CreateProcessPrcInfo.hProcess

              'If (lngExitCode <> 0&) Then Err.Raise vbObject + 1235&, "GetExitCodeProcess", "Non-zero Application exist code"
              CloseHandle hWrite
              CloseHandle hRead
          Else
              'Err.Raise vbObject + 1236&, "CreateProcess", "CreateProcess Failed, Code: " & Err.LastDllError
          End If
      End If
  End Function
```

Comment: Is this a VB6 question or a VBA question?  Mistagged?

Answer (score 2):

Pipes are buffered, but there's a limit to the buffering. When the buffer is full, the one writing to the pipe is blocked until more space is available in the buffer. Space becomes available when the pipe is read from.

Since you don't read anything from the pipe until the writer terminates, and the writer is blocked waiting for a read to occur, you have deadlock, at least until you time out. You've evidently discovered the size of the pipe's buffer.

One solution is to not wait for the writing process to terminate. Instead, just start reading, and you'll get data from the pipe as it becomes available. If you spend too much time reading, and the pipe hasn't dried up, *then* you can give up and conclude that the program is taking too long.

Comment: So then I should just take out the WaitForSingleObject completely?

Comment: Not *just* that, since there will be other changes required as well, but yes, start with not waiting for the writing process to terminate.

Comment: Ok. Now I really wish I'd worked with VB more in the beginning. Thanks for the input. I'll have to see if I can figure out how to do this.

Comment: It's nothing to do with VB, and everything to do with Win32!

Comment: Yeah. I've got it. All except for the end of the ReadFile. Right now it's stuck in a never ending loop reading the buffer. I think I need to add a watch in there to catch an exit code. That's what I'm going to add in next. Other than that, much easier than I was expecting.